# where can i see what is my current UVmap used for an object?

Tags: uv

i change textures all the time ,also i change uv maps when its needed. 
 sometimes i come back to an object and i forgot what was the uvmap that i used , 
is there a specific location or menu where i can check what was that exact uv map i used ?
was it the "cylinder projection" that i used or the "sphere projection "? 
i don't remember , but i would like to know what i did , and how to find this out. 
is it somewhere shown in an info menu ?
i could not find it.

a dot in the list would be convenient for the specific uv map that i used for this object.
 [image]

Comment: I do not think that is possible, because each of those unwrapping types have options after you click on the menu item.

Comment: but it would be a handy feature...it seems the only way to to remember what uv map i used is to write it down somewhere on a note..back to the stone age :)